# Xcode 11: cannot instantiate view controller from storyboard with identifier

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

I'm using Xcode 11.1 and my deployment target is iOS 10.0

I can't instantiate a view controller like before. Here is the code in

> func application(_ application: UIApplication,
>   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
>   [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBarController")
```

I get the error saying:

> 'instantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

How possibly can one instantiate view controllers from storyboard programmatically on Xcode 11.1. Any other way?

Comment: Please check your `Deployment target`. I think it is lower than 13.0 so you can not use this methods.

Comment: thanks @Mahendra. I solved it by changing `identifier:` to `withIdentifier` for iOS versions below 13

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use

```
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")
```

the new `instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBarController")` is only available on iOS 13 and returns `ViewController` instead of `UIViewController` as you can see here

[image]

Comment: thanks man, that was great catch with `withIdentifier:` and `identifier:`

Comment: Thanks Melian.. reason ??

Comment: How then, are you supposed to call instantiateInitialViewController og iOS < 13? They are identical in that list!

Comment: @JesperSchläger is matter of what that method returns, if you are using SwiftUI is `ViewController` and if you are using UIKit then is `UIViewController`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saved the time. @Reinier, nice catch...

Answer (score 6):

You should do following:

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")
```

parameter should be -withIdentifier- not -identifier-

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
//use instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"") method to resolve notinstantiateViewController(Identifier:"") 


 let objRef : RatindAndReviewVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RatindAndReviewVC") as! RatindAndReviewVC

       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objRef, animated: true)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.