# IBOutlet in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, iboutlet

I am trying to implement a turn-by-turn navigation app using Mapkit, all other implementations that I have found are only using Storyboard and not SwiftUI. I have found similar implementation of what I am trying to do here https://github.com/rubyvictor/MapKit-turn-by-turn-Navigation. The issue I am having is that although there are no errors no map appears when the app is run.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapboxMaps
import MapboxDirections
import MapboxCoreNavigation
import MapboxNavigation
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import AVFoundation



struct maps: View {
    
    var body: some View {
       // Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        
        MapViewWrapper()
        
        //NavigationLink("Settings", destination: Settings())
            .padding(5.0)
    }
}

struct maps_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        maps()
        
       
    }
}

struct MapViewWrapper : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  
   func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
    return ViewController()
   }
  
   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
       //uiViewController.directionsLabel.self
   }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var directionsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    //MARK: - Step three Store User Coordinates
    var currentCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var steps = [MKRoute.Step]()
    let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var stepCounter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //MARK: - Step one setup
        setupLocationManager()
    }
    
    fileprivate func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func getDirections(to destination: MKMapItem) {
        //MARK: - Step ten Initialize placemark of current coordinates and initialize mapItem with it
        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: currentCoordinates)
        let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        //MARK: - Step eleven set up direction for source and destination
        directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
        directionRequest.destination = destination
        //MARK: - Step twelve set up transport type
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
        
        //MARK: - Step thirteen Initialize directions
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculate { [weak self] (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response else { return }
            guard let mainRoute = response.routes.first else { return }
            
            
            //MARk: - Step fourteen Add polyline overlay to mapView
            self?.mapView.addOverlay(mainRoute.polyline)
            //MARK: - Step fifteen Save the steps to an empty array
            self?.steps = mainRoute.steps
            
            //MARK: - Step nineteen Before starting Monitoring, must remove monitoring regions
            self?.locationManager.monitoredRegions.forEach({ self?.locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: $0)
            })
            
            //MARk: - Step seventeen create Geofences On Polyline steps
            for i in 0..<mainRoute.steps.count {
                let step = mainRoute.steps[i]
                print(step.instructions)
                print(step.distance)
                let region = CLCircularRegion(center: step.polyline.coordinate, radius: 20, identifier: "\(i)")
                
                //MARK: - Step eighteen start monitoring region
                self?.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
                
                //MARK: - Step twenty initialize add circle overlay for region
                let circle = MKCircle(center: region.center, radius: region.radius)
                self?.mapView.addOverlay(circle)
            }
            //MARK: - Step twenty two create message to update directionsLabel for each step
            let initialMessage = "In \(self?.steps[0].distance ?? 0) metres, \(self?.steps[0].instructions ?? "") then in \(self?.steps[1].distance ?? 0) metres, \(self?.steps[1].instructions ?? "")"
            self?.directionsLabel.text = initialMessage
        
            //MARK: - Step twenty three create speechUtterance for each message
            let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: initialMessage)
            self?.speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
            self?.stepCounter += 1
            
        }
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //MARK: - Step two get user's current location
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        guard let currentLocation = locations.first else { return }
        //MARK: - Step four set current coordinate
        currentCoordinates = currentLocation.coordinate
        //MARK: - Step five set heading to track user direction
        //mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
    }
    
    //MARK: - Step twenty four
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Entered region!")
        stepCounter += 1
        if stepCounter < steps.count {
            let currentStep = steps[stepCounter]
            let message = "In \(currentStep.distance) metres, \(currentStep.instructions)"
            self.directionsLabel.text = message
            let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: message)
            speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
        } else {
            let message = "Arrived at destination"
            directionsLabel.text = message
            let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: message)
            speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
            stepCounter = 0
            self.locationManager.monitoredRegions.forEach { self.locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: $0)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //MARK: - Step six create search request
        let localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
        //MARK: - Step seven set up region with span
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentCoordinates, span: MKCoordinateSpan.init(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        
        localSearchRequest.region = region
        let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
        //MARK: - Step eight start local search
        localSearch.start { [weak self] (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                return
            }
            //MARK: - Step nine get the map items from search response
            guard let response = response else { return }
            print(response.mapItems)
            guard let firstMapItem = response.mapItems.first else { return }
            self?.getDirections(to: firstMapItem)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        
        //MARK: - step sixteen create renderer for polyline overlay
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = .blue
            renderer.lineWidth = 10
            return renderer
        }
        
        //MARK: - Step twenty one check renderer for region circle
        if overlay is MKCircle {
            let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = .orange
            renderer.fillColor = .red
            renderer.alpha = 0.5
            return renderer
        }
        
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
```

I have tried changing what is in the ContentView but I expect the issue has something to do with the IBOutlet variables, but there isn't much documentation on them. Basically, I am trying to find a to use the code in the git repo (View Controller file) and use it in SwiftUI instead storyboard.

Comment: You should post your code and not images of it. `IBOutlets` are used with Storyboards, you need to initialize your ViewController from using its storyboard, just creating it with `ViewController()` will not be sufficient to get it to work, You may find this link helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58298510/xcode-11-cannot-instantiate-view-controller-from-storyboard-with-identifier

Comment: if you have to use `@IBOutlet` in SwiftUI, I highly recommend you to review your code.

Comment: Do not use StoryBoard and SwiftUI together, never.